# PHP Tools vs VS.PHP (by DevSence vs Jcx.Software) ? Which to choose?

Tags: php, visual-studio, ide

All is in the title. I make some PHP scripts for websites but I really like Visual Studio. And I want to buy one of this extention

For me the goals are :

- Intellisence like (with variables and documentation) and just created
  class integration
- Auto-indent file with one shortcut
- Debug with beackpoint and access to "variable in stack"
- Management of "includes"
- FTP files live edit or/and publish can be a good point

So, Which to choose? Do you use one of them ?

Thanks

N

Answer (score 0):

I use the Zend Studio.  It does all the thing you are looking to do.  I think there is even a free licence - if you are in to licenses.  You can get the same thing (I think) by install eclipse and doing the independant install of different packages.  I tried it one time and was unsuccessful (that was a million years ago).  I tried the visual studio plugg-in  ( I really like visual studio - don't like micro soft).  I dont think I got it to work as promised.  That too was a million years ago.  I used the Zend Studio + Zend server and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Old question and I am sure you have already made your decision, but for the benefit of Googlers I too was looking to use Visual Studio with PHP and here is what I concluded.

First, I spend most of my time developing in c#/.Net, so VS is my IDE of choice and I really like it. I have a few PHP projects that I work on occasionally and do not have a lot of time to dedicate to them. I did try using editors built for PHP such as PHPStorm and I do think they are a better choice for PHP if that is you main thing, but ultimately I felt like too much of my mental effort was spent switching gears and learning a new IDE instead of getting something accomplished.

So that leaves PHP Tools and VS.PHP. My choice is PHP Tools simply because it appears to have more support and ongoing development. PHP Tools is very active on social media and has developed a VS 2017 version. VS.PHP has not posted any social media since 2015 and as of yet does not have a 2017 version.

Answer (score 0):

For years I have used JCX VS.PHP for Visual Studio but the last update was Dec 2016 and VS.PHP is no longer being sold. The last version of JCX VS.PHP was for VS 2015. There will not be a version for VS 2017. It appears you can still download the last updated version of JCX VS.PHP for VS 2015. But if I was making this decision today I would go with PHP Tools and in fact you will have to go with PHP Tools if you want to use VS 2017 and above. It is really to bad JCX VS.PHP stopped development I really like the product and was very productive with it. By the way if you can in fact download the latest VS.PHP for free and are willing to continue with VS 2015 it still is a great development environment for PHP under Visual Studio. You just won't get support.